# Is $|\tau(s)| = \sqrt{- \kappa}$ true in asymptotic curve

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\alpha(s)$ be an asymptotic curve on a surface $S$ with Gaussian curvature $\kappa$ so that the curvature of $\alpha$ is never zero. Prove that the torsion $\tau(s)$ of α satisfies $|\tau(s)| = \sqrt{- \kappa}$.

Curve $\alpha$ is called asymptotic if its normal curvature is everywhere zero. Note that $\kappa \leq 0$ at all points $\alpha$ passes through because otherwise there wouldn’t be any asymptotic directions at those points.)

Comment: Welcome to MSE - please see [How can I format mathematics here?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Comment: You can find hints regarding your question **[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3202373/asymptotic-curve-with-negative-gauss-curvature-show-taup-sqrt-kp?rq=1)**